# Endomorphism rings of vector spaces are primitive

Tags: ring-theory, modules

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_ring, the endomorphism ring of a vector space is primitive.  I'm trying to see why this is true without success.  Is there an obvious faithful module over $End(V)$ that I'm failing to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an obvious faithful [simple]  module over $End(V)$ that I'm failing to see?

Yes, the module $V$.